# Mongoose DBRef remove original schema removal to remove DBRefs and pull out from DBRef Array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, model, mongoose, dbref

In **Mongoose**,

I can declare **Schemas** and also I can use

[DBRef](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

which is simply putting **ObjectId or an Array of ObjectId**

and **populate(get)** those items.

I think it would be problem when **a DBRef removal is needed**.

Is there any way to possibly **sync removal of DBref**?

### For example

1. **Removal of a DBRef** from an array should **remove** that of DBRef in other collections and also **pull out** that DBRef from arrays of DBRef in different collections
2. **Removal** of a document (DBRef from this document's Schema) also **removes** that of DBRef in other collections and also **pull out** that DBRef from arrays of DBRef in different collections

Are these **possible**? If so, **how can I achieve these**? Or any other **Model design suggestions**?

Comment: There seens to be some confusion here: mongoose's `populate` doesn't make use of DBRef, it is simply another query (a manual reference as explained).
See the difference here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/database-references/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `schema.pre('remove', ...` [middleware](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) to implement your own cascaded removal of ObjectId references in other collections.  `this._id` identifies the document being removed in your middleware function.